# Mixing values of multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array

```
array (
     array (
      'id_product' => '10',
      'id_supplier' => '0'
     ),
     array (
      'id_product' => '11',
      'id_supplier' => '0'
     )
)
```

and a second one I want to merge with first one

```
array (
     array (
      'id_product' => '10',
      'date' => '12/02/2014'
     )
)
```

I need to get

```
array (
     array (
      'id_product' => '10',
      'id_supplier' => '0',
      'date' => '12/02/2014'
     ),
     array (
      'id_product' => '11',
      'id_supplier' => '0'
     )
)
```

I know I could use a foreach in one and look for an existing value in the second one but what's the most efficient way? Is there a php function for that kind of mixing? I looked to array_merge() but doesn't seems what I need

Comment: `foreach` will do just fine. No, there's no existing function for exactly this.

Comment: You would have more options if the values for `id_product` are in the keys.

Comment: I agree but can't change that

Comment: array_replace_recursive() is the function I was looking for and indeed exists ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following deceze comment, I ended up using:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2)
        if ($value1['id_product'] == $value2['id_product'])
        {
            $array1[$key] = array_merge($array1[$key], $array2[$key2]);
        }
}
```

this function gave me same result, thanks to TBI, but only if I needed to merge arrays based on their position within $a and $b, witch isn't the case

```
$result = array_replace_recursive(array1, array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code:-

```
$a = array (
     array (
      'id_product' => '10',
      'id_supplier' => '0'
     ),
     array (
      'id_product' => '11',
      'id_supplier' => '0'
     )
);

$b = array (
     array (
      'id_product' => '10',
      'date' => '12/02/2014'
     )
);
function my_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        $a++;
        echo $a;
        if(!empty($array2[$key]) && !empty($array2[$key])){
            $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $array2[$key]);
        }
        if(empty($array2[$key])){
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$array = my_array_merge($a, $b);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$a = array (
 array (
  'id_product' => '10',
  'id_supplier' => '0'
 ),
 array (
  'id_product' => '11',
  'id_supplier' => '0'
 ));

$b = array (
 array (
  'id_product' => '10',
  'date' => '12/02/2014'
 ));
```

I have used array_merge_recursive function to get the combined array :-

```
$c = array_replace_recursive($a, $b);
```

**$c** is the result that you wanted to show.

Comment: Let's assume for a moment that `$b[0]['id_product']` is actually `'11'`; in that case, your code doesn't work.

Comment: seems like the easiest solution and exactly fitting my needs, thanks

Comment: @Axi This happens to work because the two arrays to merge are both the first in the list. If that's your logic, if you want to merge arrays based on their *position* within `$a` and `$b`, great! But if you want to merge based on the `id_product` key, this isn't it.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for this comment, I didn't realize that! I need to merge based on id_product. I'll try to update accepted answer